# Get percentage complete from number of iterations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am trying to compute the percentage complete of a program that has a loop with a variable number of iterations.

For example:
The progress will always be set at 30% just before entering the loop and should be just below or at 100% right after exiting the loop. I need to calculate the percentages inside of the loop so that it does not drop below the previous value. So if the loop iterates 5 times I need the percentage to increment accordingly based on the number of iterations.

Right now the formula I have is:

```
currentProgress / numIterations + (currentIterationNum - 1) / numIterations * 100
```

The problem I am having now is that when I enter the loop with 5 iterations and the current progress is at 30%  the returned value is 6.

```
30/5+(1-1)/5*100 = 6
30/5+(1-1)/5*100 = 26
30/5+(1-1)/5*100 = 46
30/5+(1-1)/5*100 = 66
30/5+(1-1)/5*100 = 86
```

As previously stated I need to get a value back above 30%. Math is not my strong point so I am hoping someone here can help me figure out what I am doing wrong. I feel this question is best suited here because it is based on math and not strictly programming. I am not sure if this is based on Algebra or Calculus so forgive me if I tagged it incorrectly.

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that the loop consumes 70% of the execution time independent of the the number of times it iterates. Are you sure that's what you want? If the loop runs just once (in some special case) then that single iteration takes up 70% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

You "enter the loop" at *k* = *initialIterations*, want that to appear as 30%.

You know at the time of entering how much more iterations the loop will go through: *j*=*additionalIterations*.

You want to "leave the loop" at *z*=*j+k*, and this should be displayed as 100%

So $$valueDisplayed= 30+{(currentIteration-initialIterations)\over(initialIterations+additionalIterations)}70 $$

Should do the trick